# Does MATLAB support nested variable scopes?

Tags: matlab

Can MATLAB define variables like the following pseudo C-like code?

```
{  
    int a = 0;
    int b, c;
    {
       int a = 42; 
       b = a;
    }
    c = a;
}
```

We could use nested functions to 'simulate' this. Can we do this w/o using functions?

I asked this because there are some C code that I wanted to convert to MATLAB. I was wondering how to convert the nested variable declarations to MATLAB.

Thank you,

Comment: I don't understand the purpose.

Comment: Can you even do this with nested functions?

Comment: The only way way I know to do this with nested functions is to pass `a` as a parameter to the nested function. Otherwise it will use the parent's `a`.

Comment: I updated the question to explain why I wanted to do so. Passing a as parameters would not work. In C, the inner a would shadow the outer a. I guess I have to rename the inner a to make this work, otherwise the outer a is overwritten in MATLAB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is impossible directly. The good news is that this is probably fine, because it is difficult to read and properly maintain code that has similarly named variables all over the place. The simplest solution would be to rename the variables:

```
{  
    int a = 0;
    int b, c;
    {
       int a = 42; 
       b = a;
    }
    c = a;
}
```

would become (in MATLAB):

```
a = 0;
d = 42;
b = d;
c = a;
```

If "inner" `a` and "outer" `a` are doing different things, you will do no harm by giving them different names, and perhaps even save someone a maintenance nightmare later down the line.

Comment: Heh. Easiest "No" answer I ever made.